# Difference in between similar type constraint and conditional type

Tags: typescript, type-constraints, conditional-types

I have written my own implementation of the build-in utility-type `InstanceType`:

```
type MyInstanceType<C extends abstract new (...args: any) => any>
  = C extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never
```

It is very close to how it is actually implemented:

```
type BuiltInInstanceType<C extends abstract new (...args: any) => any>
  = C extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any
```

the only difference is that I'm having last word `never` while actual implementation has there `any`

It results in a difference in how it treats `any`:

```
type MyWithAny = MyInstanceType<any> // unknown
type BuiltInWithAny = BuiltInInstanceType<any> // any
```

I assume that it means that it is somehow getting to the falsy branch of the conditional type

So the question is, how is this possible? Considering that conditional type is the same as type constraint and so anything that is falsy to the conditional type should also be falsy to type constraint and so should result in a type constraint failed error

And the second question, why `MyWithAny` is exactly `unknown` and not e.g. `never`?

**UPD**: based on the answer and discussion, this is how it's getting evaluated (more details in the accepted answer):

1. Usage of `any` as an argument to the generic function when evaluating `MyWithAny` and `BuiltInWithAny` has completely disabled the type constraints. So `MyInstanceType` has been evaluated like it's

```
type MyInstanceType<C> = C extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never
```

and `BuiltInInstanceType` has been evaluated like it's

```
type BuiltInInstanceType<C> = C extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any
```

that makes falsy branches possible

2. In case when TS cannot evaluate the branch of a conditional type, it evaluates it to a union type of both branches. So because `any` includes instances that may or may not satisfy the conditional type, the type of `MyWithAny` is becoming `R | never` and the type of `BuiltInWithAny` is becoming `R | any`
3. In case when TS cannot resolve `R` it considers as `unknown`. So, the result type of `MyWithAny` is `unknown | never` that is `unkonown`, and the result type of `BuiltInWithAny` is `unknown | any` that is `any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example can be reduced to smth like this:

```js
type WithNever = <T>(t: T) => T | never
type WithAny = <T>(t: T) => T | any

type NeverRetutn = ReturnType<WithNever>
type AnyRetutn = ReturnType<WithAny>
```

We are interested in `T | never` and `T | any`.

If TypeScript is unable to infer type of `T`, TS will assign `unknown` type.

See example:

```js
type ReturnUnknown = ReturnType< <T>(t: T) => T> // unknown
```

What is `never`? ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never))

> The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type

In fact, you should treat `never` as empty union.

```js
type Check = 1 | never // 1
type Check2 = unknown | never // unknown
type Check3 = any | never // any
```

As you might have noticed, `never` is assigned to every type.

Let's go back to your question. In fact,  you are receiving union of types.

```js
type MyWithAny = MyInstanceType<any> // R | never
type BuiltInWithAny = BuiltInInstanceType<any> // R | any
```

I hope, it is clear now, that `R | never` will be resolved as `unknown`, because `R` is unknown and `never` is assignable to unknown.

`R | any` is the same as `unknown | any`, and because any type is assignable to `any` you are getting just `any`.

But why you are receiving the union of types?
It is clear that  conditional type should return true or false branch, but not both. This is not how it works in TS.

Because you have provided `any` as an argument every branch is applied. I think it is expected, because I don't have enough arguments to say that only true branch should be applied, or only false branch.

> Considering that conditional type is the same as type constraint and so anything that is falsy to the conditional type should also be falsy to type constraint and so should result in a type constraint failed error

Since `any` type is in fact any type (every type), why do you think `false` branch should be applied ? Keep in mind, you are working with types, not the values.

> What is confusing to me about falsy branch is that how I understand it, it should always be evacuated to never, no matter what we put there

It can't be always evaluated to false branch. Such assumption is not correct.

Consider next example:

```js
type CheckAny = any extends abstract new (...args: any) => any ? true : false
```

Above condition evaluates to `true | false`. And `true | false` union is just a built in `boolean` type.

I don't think typescript is not smart enough. TS just tells you that `any` type can extend constructor type but in the same time it can not extend.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, with the conversion of conditional type to union type it is starting to make sense. What is confusing to me about falsy branch is that how I understand it, it should always be evacuated to `never`, no matter what we put there. Because it is equal to the type constraint that would never allow it to be evaluated. Would it be correct to assume that TypeScript is just not smart enough to derive this? And so, it makes a union type with a value from the falsy branch, and so, we are seen different type results

Comment: Of course, what you wrote is correct. But why would it be correct if we would add a type constraint similar to conditional type? `type CheckAny<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any> = T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any ? true : false`. As a person I understand that `false` is not possible (anything that could evaluate to `false` would rise an error) and so it should be `true` but TS is evaluating this to `boolean`

Comment: Oh, I got it. See docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any  . `any` type is considered an unsafe type. It was provided to TS type system to make migration from JS to TS easier. It is something we have to live with )). `unknown` type is much safer.

Comment: Ok, let's simplify it even further: `type AlwaysTrue<T extends number> = T extends number ? true : false` and then `type TrueOrCompileError = AlwaysTrue<any>`. TS would evaluate `TrueOrCompileError` to `boolean`. Can I assume that using `any` is completely disabling the type constraint, even for the stage when the conditional type is getting evaluated (as union) and so the result type includes `false` (although with the type constraint it is impossible to reach and so equivalent to `never`)?

Comment: @Agat yes you can assume it completely disabling type constraints.